# Видео с бегущей строкой android

Tags: android, textview, mediaplayer, videoview

Здравствуйте. Необходимо было сделать Activity с видео во весь экран и поверх него бегущей строкой. Все это я реализовал, но когда нужно проигрывать видео бОльших размеров (вплоть до 1080р) все жутко лагает, иногда проскакивает

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Код для приложения простейший:

```
<VideoView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/videoView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

Код Activity:

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus(0);
    videoView.start();
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mText.setText("Много текста ");
    mText.setSelected(true);
```

Приложение для AndroidTV, поэтому необходимо воспроизведение такого качественного видео. Пробовал и VideoView, и mediaplayer + surfaceView, и exoPlayer. 
Собственно вопрос: что можно с этим сделать, чтобы приложение не тормозило?

Comment: а без "бегущей строки" не тормозит?

Comment: @metalurgus, без бегущей строки все отлично.

Comment: а насколько длинный текст в TextView? сколько символов?

Comment: @metalurgus не считал, каждый раз по разному, но текст всегда не помещается в экран.

Comment: Пробовали запустить видео в отдельном трэде?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не знаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать не VideoView, а MediaPlayer в связке с SurfaceView, при этом переопределив Surface (идея не моя, взята отсюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772575/how-to-add-textview-to-dynamic-surfaceview-android)
как и код:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

Paint paint;

public MySurfaceView() {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(25);

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public class onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawText("Your Text", 10, 10, paint);
}

}
```